# Parents / child origin and movement problems. Attack on Titan swinging from hooks

Tags: animation, camera, constraints, origin, hook-modifier

I am currently making an AoT animation and working on the swinging from hooks. I used this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UO0OM0plOX0 to get an idea of how to make animated hooks and rope and it mostly worked. So I have a camera, a character with "child of" to make it move like the cam, 2 bezier (ropes) coonected to the character using empties and 1 empties at the end of each rope for the hook.

The problem : https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Pzn.jpg

When the character moves, the empties leave parenting lines behind, and the origins of the ropes also stays behind, making animating the other movements of the scene impossible...

Did i do anything wrong here ?

Comment: Please add your image into your question rather than just posting a link to it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Agreed. 
Also hooks don't alter origins, what you see as relationship line is the line to where the hook object needed to be in order to nullify the effect of the hook, ie where it was when the hook was created.

Comment: Sorry about the image thing, it is a copy paste of the question i asked on reddit. As for the problem, is there a better way to do what i'm doing ? Or do i need to work around it ?